# Get the conditional updated value in the SQL code

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query:

```
select round(((avg(counts) * 100) * table2.times) / 100, 2) as Average, userid 
from table1
inner join table2 on table1.userid = table2.ufkuserid
```

Now in `table1` one column has values of `PP,RE,NE`

Based upon the above 3 `PE,RE,NE`, I want to change the `table2.times` value to be `15,20,30`

But I have to use SQL code to map and change it, otherwise I am stuck.

So `table2.times` have to be hardcoded values to be `15,20,30`.

Comment: Please show some sample data and desired results.

Comment: Your query is syntactically incorrect without a `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select ROUND(((AVG(counts) * 100) * v.times) / 100, 2) AS Average,
       userid 
from table1 inner join
     table2 
     on table1.userid = table2.ufkuserid cross apply
     (values (case table1.onecolumn
                  when 'PE' then 15.0 when 'RE' then 20.0 when 'NE' then 30.0
              end)
     ) v(times)
group by userid;
```

Comment: hmm, cross apply, i gotta try it, but i am checking something like a case statement 
`ROUND(((AVG(counts) * 100) * 
case WHEN table1.column = 'PE' THEN '30' ELSE table1.times END,
case WHEN table1.column = 'RE' THEN '30' ELSE table1.times END,
case WHEN table1.column = 'NE' THEN '30' ELSE table1.times END,

) / 100, 2) AS Average`

Comment: but something is rong in the syntax

Comment: but really confused with your syntax

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c885b726e7046123f63ee72b0b8e701c

Comment: something like above i am trying

Comment: @Attaire You need to show your complete code - that snippet doesn't tell us what you are doing. And if you show some sample data and expected results as requested you'll get an answer much faster.

Comment: @Attaire . . . You have put a syntactically incorrect fragment of code in a db fiddle, and no sample data.  There is nothing to look at.

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for an UPDATE statement for table2?

```
update t2
set
  times=t1.times
from
  table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on t1.userid = t2.ufkuserid;
```